Word or concise way to describe the emotional contrast of a cemetery in a beautiful sunny day
The other day I was walking in Bunhill Fields cemetery, central London. It's in a very lively area and many people populate it during the day, due to its closeness to office spaces and schools. It's filled with tombstones and leaf-filled trees, which give it the typical aspect of a cemetery, but it also has open spaces where people walk, sit down on benches, have lunch, talk and laugh.
The day was bright, sunny, and there was no wind. I visited after peak time, so there weren't many people around, but the feeling wasn't of a typical cemetery – it looked like a place for the dead that had just been left silent by a multitude of living people. The sunlight shone on the trees creating mesmerizing shadows on the tombstones and on the ground. There was an eery contrast between the spirit of the cemetery and its potential liveliness.
I kept thinking whether there could be an adjective or a concise way to describe this. It was melancholic, in a way, but the sunlight and the general feeling wasn't quite gloomy, although the tombstones did slightly inspire that.

juxtaposition? But I didn't read it all. Laziness makes me seem more talented; it's the juxtaposition of it all.

It's an "ambivalent feeling", but the expression doesn't precisely convey the opposition between gloomy and joyfull.

"Gravely beautiful" -- can you dig it? :-)

This question is similar to: I need a word that is suggests both positively and negatively, good and bad. Almost like bittersweet. If you believe it’s different, please [edit] the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

Contrast between what and what? Please be clearer.

Oddly uplifting.


bittersweet (Oxford English Dictionary)
(figurative) Designating something, such as an experience or emotion, that is both pleasant and tinged with pain or sadness.


"Truth faced leaves a strange taste / when joy and sadness meet / A country rain on a city street / This life is bittersweet."  These lyrics came to mind immediately when reading the question.  https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=v4WfbSMMWhk

The word goes back a long way - I thought about including the full OED's first citeation: ***c1405 (c1395)
Vn-to hem it is a bitter sweete [c1425 Petworth MS. bitterswete].

G. Chaucer, Canon's Yeoman's Tale (Ellesmere MS.) (1875) l. 878*** - but apart from knowing who Chaucer was, I don't really understand any of that!

glukupikron: Sophos seems to have come up with the same word. (Greek lyric poetry)

The SOED definition is "(fig) agreeable or pleasant with an alloy of pain or bitterness"; there has been a shift  from "bitterness" to "sadness" in the full OED, somehow:   those feelings are clearly not the same. Moreover, the feeling associated with death is overwhelmingly a feeling of sadness;  to top it all, this feeling is associated only with people who have lost someone dear to them. A mere visitor to a graveyard can't feel sadness nor sadness in the place, much less bitterness; in my opinion, the general observer has to be left with another impression, be in another state of mind.

The glorious weather seemed incongruous amidst the tombstones and offerings to the dead.
definitions of incongruous:

not in harmony or keeping with the surroundings or other aspects of something.
Oxford Language's online dictionary -

...

Someone or something that is incongruous seems strange when considered together with other aspects of a situation.
Collins Dictionary - https://www.collinsdictionary.com/us/dictionary/english/incongruous


This word shows contrast but doesn't have that emotional aspect the poster is looking for. Bittersweet captures that sentiment well.

@user405662 true, but the other option was "concise way to describe".  I think I managed that, emotional content and all.

"Wistful" came to my mind to describe the sadness and beauty of a cemetery in the sunshine. It captures both the feeling and the way it's expressed. You may have looked wistful yourself while observing the tombstones, the trees and the sunlight.

Elegiac
The elegiac was originally a meter.  The Romantics praised it as suitable for reflective poetry, and it came to be used so widely for poetry on the dead that "elegy" now means a poem in memory of the dead.
However, from its original, it still carries connotations of reflectiveness and thought, not wild and uncontrollable grief.

Not a term specific to the description of an opposition between liveliness and the solemn introverted moods associated with things religious, the term "antithetical" still captures in a basic way the contrast involved, although I would agree that it confers merely the idea of the skeleton in a concept we sense as having flesh also (one should keep to the usual bounds that this traditional analogy entails). If short of a pithy means of expression under the pen of the seminal writer, this term will certainly be useful to the literary critic.

(SOED) antithetical 1 Of the nature of antithesis; containing or using antithesis. 2 Characterized by direct opposition (to).
antithetic a. antithetical


(SOED) antithesis 4 Direct or striking opposition of character or function (of, between two things).
5 The direct opposite, a complete contrast, (of, to).


A cemetery is a liminal space. It is a place of transition between living and dead. Liminal spaces are typically unsettling.
From Merriam-Webster:

2:  of, relating to, or being an intermediate state, phase, or condition : in-between, transitional
… in the liminal state between life and death. —Deborah Jowitt

